# Can I make an XML attribute mandatory via XSLT depending on value of another attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

[Edited]

My knowledge in xsd/xslt is very limited so forgive me if my question is very basic or somehow unclear. I think my need is basic but I may be confused with the terms as I couldn't find any related or close answers.

I have the following structure in my .xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="someelement">
  ...
  <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:NCName"/>
  ...
  <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:NCName"/>
  ...
```

I know that in the .xsd I can set use="Required" to make an attribute mandatory. (by mandatory I mean if should fail validation)

But in my case, "attr1" should be mandatory only if "attr2" has a certain value.

Can this be done? (in the .xsd file or .xslt?)

I wish to accomplish this behaviour:

`if element is “someelement” and 
    attribute "attr2" equal "somevalue" then 
       set use="Required" for "attr1"
    else
       "attr1" should not be mandatory`

Comment: What about a if statement for the specific attribute?

Comment: Тhe subject line says "XSLT", you have shown some snippets that looks close to a schema snippet. So what are you looking for, a way to implement your requirement in the schema language? Or a way to manipulate a schema (as the XML input) with XSLT? Also it is not clear what you refer to with the word "attribute", it has a clear meaning in the context of XML/XSLT/schemas, but given that your snippet has `xs:element name="attribute"`, e.g. an element declaration for an element named "attribute", I am not sure what you want to make mandatory.

Comment: And do you really want an attribute named `xsitype`, or are you really thinking of `xsi:type`, which has a special meaning for schema validation?

Comment: I guess my example is not very clear, forgive me as my knowledge of xsd/xslt is close to none. I am editing my example hopefully to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard `xsi:type` attribute, then this must refer to a type declaration in the schema, and the type declaration it refers to can be a restriction of the default type that defines the other attribute to be required.

If you want to use a user-defined attribute like your confusingly-named `xsitype`, that has no special meaning to the schema processor, then the way to achieve this is with conditional type assignment (aka xs:alternative), which requires an XSD 1.1 processor.

*UPDATE (ADDRESSING THE REVISED QUESTION)*

You can't achieve this in XSD 1.0. It can be done in XSD 1.1 using conditional type assignment (aka xs:alternative). You define two types, `typeA` with `attr1` optional and `typeB` with `attr1` required, and you then define the type of `someElement` using `xs:alternative` so it has `typeA` when `@attr eq 'someValue'` and `typeB` otherwise. Typically `typeB` will be defined as a restriction of `typeA`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please see my edits, I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: It's an improvement, though I think your question has nothing to do with XSLT.